# Hot to add mutliple items to Listview simple_list_item_1

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I got a ListView and an ArrayList. How to add new items dynamically without lose the existing?
For example I add 'John' using `addChatv2("John")`, but actually delete the exisitng ones.

**Edit:**
The name should be added from another function.

**Edit 2:**
I made chat_name and arrayAdapter global.

```
private List<String> chat_name;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;



private String addChatv2(String name) {
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatlist);

chat_name = new ArrayList<String>();

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        chat_name);

lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
//chat_name.add(name);
//arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

return name;
}
```

Comment: I am new to android and java. Please comment if I made any mistake.

Comment: I could be wrong but if you call that same function twice, you replace the List<String> with a new ArrayList<String> which will replace the list you just made with a blank new one.

Comment: I already fixed my problem, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

just add another name in the chat_name list . and call the notifyDatasetChanged funtion again

```
chat_name.add("another name to add");
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you want to add the name from some other function. Then you might want to make the arrayAdapter global. Because otherwise you won't be able to call it.

Comment: Could you expand your example by calling it from another function?

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<String> chat_name;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

private void addChatv2() {
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatlist);

    chat_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    chat_name.add("John");

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            chat_name);

    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //test
    addChatv2();
    chat_name.add("Tester");
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```